# C: unable to iniitliaze 2D arrays with 1D arrays in Atmel Studios

Tags: c, arrays, atmelstudio

So I'm trying to create a 2D array by doing the following:

```
unsigned char seqA[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
unsigned char seqB[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4};
unsigned char seqC[] = {3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4};
unsigned char seqD[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5};
unsigned char seq[][10] = {seqA, seqB, seqC, seqD};
```

And I'm getting a large amount of errors from trying to do so:

```
Warning 1   missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]    C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Warning 2   (near initialization for 'seq[0]') [-Wmissing-braces]   C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Warning 3   initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]   C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Warning 4   (near initialization for 'seq[0][0]') [enabled by default]  C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Error   5   initializer element is not computable at load time  C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Error   6   (near initialization for 'seq[0][0]')   C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Warning 7   initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]   C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Warning 8   (near initialization for 'seq[0][1]') [enabled by default]  C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Error   9   initializer element is not computable at load time  C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Error   10  (near initialization for 'seq[0][1]')   C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Warning 11  initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]   C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Warning 12  (near initialization for 'seq[0][2]') [enabled by default]  C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Error   13  initializer element is not computable at load time  C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Error   14  (near initialization for 'seq[0][2]')   C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Warning 15  initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]   C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Warning 16  (near initialization for 'seq[0][3]') [enabled by default]  C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Error   17  initializer element is not computable at load time  C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
Error   18  (near initialization for 'seq[0][3]')   C:\Users\Jonathan\Documents\Atmel Studio\6.2\GccApplication3\GccApplication3\GccApplication3.c  135 1   GccApplication3
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`seq` is a Array of type `char`, you are trying to initialize with `address to char`.

Replace

```
unsigned char seq[][10] = {seqA, seqB, seqC, seqD};
```

with

```
unsigned char* seq[] = {seqA, seqB, seqC, seqD};
```

Now if you want to read 3rd element of `seqA` then use:

`*(seq[0] +2)`  OR `seq[0][2]`

Comment: Ended up doing that. Thanks.

Comment: Why not just seq[0][2]?

Comment: @jschultz410 no problem in using that also.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's a specific reason to name the individual rows, the most efficient (and, in my opinion, clearest) thing to do would be

```
static const unsigned char seq[][10] =
  { {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4},
    {3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 4},
    {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5} };
```

I also added `const`, which, provided the data is really constant, can help the optimizer do a better job in certain situations, and `static`, which makes it clear that `seq` is only used within that file (if that is the case).

If `seq` is only used within one particular function, you could take it further by moving it into that function. In that case you'd definitely want `static` as the compiler would have to generate code to put the values on the stack otherwise.

Using the pointer solution, you'll have four extra pointers and an extra pointer dereference for every access.